# Can I add a check constraint to a child checking the value of its parent in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a similar database with two tables as follow:

```
+----------------------+           +------------------------+
|Persons               |           |phones                  |
+----------------------+           +------------------------+
|id       int          +-----+     |id          int         |
|name     varchar(100) |     +---->+person_id   int         |
|allowed  tinyint(1)   |           |number      int         |
+----------------------+           +------------------------+
```

One person could have as many phones as he wants but he has to be allowed to it (allowed > 0).

So, I created both tables using

```
CREATE TABLE `phones` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `persons_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phonenumber` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `phones_ibfk_1` (`persons_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phones_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`persons_id`) REFERENCES `persons` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`
```

But this doesn't check what I want. What I want to know if it is possible make a query like `ALTER TABLE phones ADD CONSTRAINT chk_person CHECK (persons.allowed  > 0)`. Is this possible? There's another alternative?

Comment: Pointless effort. If `allowed` is `0`, then in your serverside code simply don't perform inserts. Relational databases take care of **relations**, not **permissions**. Also, if a person has `n` records in `phones` and you set their `allowed` to `0`, then your serverside code can simply ignore the query towards `phones` and display nothing. You don't have to use RDBMS to do every single thing, it takes care of data and not what someone can or can't do.

Comment: @Mjh DB take care of data integrity.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding the idea of the constraint that you are asking to be built .Anyway a check constraint of the type chk_constraint ChECK (persons.allowed>0) i dont think that its possible .

Comment: @Golinmarq You probably will need a trigger to handle that restriction.

Comment: @N.B. Well if you dont have time why you write in first place. I dont get offended but you deserve a reply. Because ppl like me doesnt get 17k rep just because the good look or charm, but for helping a lot. My first comment was necesary because Mjh say something wrong, and if you check carefully is his comment the one really useless. Then my `trigger` comment point OP in the right direction. Of course isnt a full answer, but that is what comment are for. I could write a full answer, but you dont decide how I spend my time here.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks man! this could be a possible solution but, I tried to avoid it in first place and try to validate data server side. The allowed field will not change once is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the check constraint doesn't work a solution is to create a trigger before
insert so you check the values if you find something wron do an insert into the same table that will cause a erreur in

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER  trigger_check  before insert ON phones  FOR EACH ROW 
begin 
DECLARE is_allowed boolean;
select allowed into @is_allowed from Persons where id = new.person_id;
if @is_allowed <1 then 
  insert into phones values ('','','','');  #make erreur doesn't metter
  end if ;
end ||
DELIMITER ;
```

that's how we do it for now hope that check constraint work in the new versions

Comment: Thanks! This could be a solution