# mysql insert only if not exists doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I read some threads about this topic and tried so much but my code does not work. If a dataset already exists in my table, i do not want to insert it twice.

My table "WORD" with some example data (id is auto increment).

```
id | customer_id | category_id | word | comment
1      3             5           life   null
2      5             5           motor   tbd
3      null          2           Day     week
```

I ONLY want to check customer_id, category_id, word. If the new row has exactly same customer_id, category_id and word, I don't want to insert it. comment and id dosn't matter.

My Code:

```
insert into word (customer_id, category_id, word) 
select * from (select null, 2, 'Day') as tmp 
where not exists (select * from word where customer_id=null and category_id=2 and word='Day')
limit 1
```

THIS is inserted :(
He is inserting it, though I have a row (id =3) with null/2/Day. The new inserted one has comment null, the othe hast comment week, but this doesn't matter.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: check this answer     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399718/can-i-add-a-check-constraint-to-a-child-checking-the-value-of-its-parent-in-mysq/38400520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from word where customer_id=null
```

Should be

```
select * from word where customer_id IS NULL
```

See this site in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

A way to dodge the workaround in your statement would be to set an unique index on those columns, if your usecases allow the constraint. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE
>   index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.
>   If you specify a prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE index, the
>   column values must be unique within the prefix.

Comment: " =null"....shame on me. Thank you guys! That was also the reason why rows with customer_id worked fine, and the one with null not.