# mysql insert if not exists doesn't work creating duplicate keys

Tags: mysql

although i am using  mysql "insert ignore" statement

to insert a row to a table  called software

i want to make sure that i will not insert a software that already exists in the table.

my table called software and i want to insert

new software to this table but if its already

exists in the table,i want the skip the insert

my table looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | software1 |
|  2 | software2|
|  3 | software3   |
|  4 | software4   |
|    |
+----+-----------+
```

i used "insert ignore" but still its creates duplicate keys

```
MariaDB [db]> insert ignore into software values (5,'software4');
```

now i can see that there is a duplicate software4 key

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | software1 |
|  2 | software2|
|  3 | software3   |
|  4 | software4   |
|  5   software4
+----+-----------+
```

although i can see similar question here:

[mysql insert only if not exists doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425619/mysql-insert-only-if-not-exists-doesnt-work)

as i am mysql newbie it didn't help me

Comment: How is your table defined, especially in regards to keys or (unique) indexes?

Comment: @koren were any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 1):

check: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-ignore/
"By using the IGNORE keyword all errors are converted to warnings, which will not stop inserts of additional rows."

If you do not want to have duplicate entries in name, make them UNIQUE:

CREATE TABLE t1 (x int UNIQUE);

Answer (score 1):

First Make the `name` column unique so you are sure that there are no duplicate entries:

`ALTER TABLE software  ADD UNIQUE (name);`

And then use `INSERT IGNORE...` which will only `INSERT` if it still doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO software (id, name)
SELECT 4, 'software4'
FROM software
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM software WHERE name = 'software4'
) LIMIT 1;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=11169c53ac2c20afc62b043249bd3e3b)

This will insert the record, only when the name is not already existing.

Comment: `insert into software` vs. `select from ignore`. Are you sure this does what you are claiming?

Comment: If you dont provide me a fiddle to test, then you need to test it. But i am pretty sure it works :)

Comment: "WHERE" is not permitted without "FROM".

Comment: Yes you are right. I've edited my post with a demo and a working solution!